# Why Flatpak Chromium's decision to use or not use /run/user/…/doc/ depends on the save destination?

Tags: chrome, download, flatpak

I found out that clicking "Show in folder" in my Flatpak Chromium's download history sometimes leads to `/run/user/<user-id>/doc/<dir-id>/`.

I've done basic googling to find out that this directory is somehow used by the Flatpak apps. I also see that it contains something like hardlinks to the real files, which are present in various original saving locations as well.

However, I see that `/run/...` is not used for all downloads. When saving to a mounted NTFS or even to `/tmp`, it's used. When saving to `~/Downloads` or just `~`, it's not used.

1. What are the rules here? Is "everything under ~" getting special treatment?
2. I think that "Open in folder" navigating to this weird location instead of the actual folder where the file is also present (e.g. NTFS) looks like a bug. Is it? If so, what level should it be reported — Chromium? Flatpak? My distro?